# how to get rotated image region?

Tags: android, math, rotation, bounding-box

For example I got a picture position in 10,10 with width of 100 and height of 120. I centre rotated it clock-wise 20 degree, the position will be smaller and size will be bigger since the edge will be coming out, but how would I calculate the value for them?

No sure I made the question clear enough, will change it if I find a better way to explain it.

Trying to do this in Android

Comment: The easiest way to express such things is to provide a picture outlining with paint or whatever program what you want to calculate

Comment: that is what I'm trying to accomplish, I want to know how to draw the outline(from where and how big is it) since the actual picture file didn't rotate; it just rotate when it's drawn on the canvas

Comment: I want the value of the outline because I can use it for other detection, such as collision and click detection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to know how the bounding box of an object is transformed if you rotate it around its center.

If the original box has width w and height h, the new one, after rotation by r, has dimensions:

w<sub>r</sub> = abs(sin(r)) * h + abs(cos(r)) * w
h<sub>r</sub> = abs(sin(r)) * w + abs(cos(r)) * h

Comment: this is what I did base on your formula
width2 = ((Math.abs(Math.sin(angle))*height) + (Math.abs(Math.cos(angle))*width));
height2 = ((Math.abs(Math.sin(angle))*width) + (Math.abs(Math.cos(angle))*height)));

but the result are not as expected, from a single angle increase height/width can go from 235 to 197, am I doing something wrong?